# How to create popup new window browser with small size

Tags: javascript

i tried to create link, if clicked will be popout a new windows browser with small size, i tried this code

```
<p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
}
</script>
```

the result is it success move to other link but opened in new tab on parent browser, what i tried to create is link opened in new window browser with small size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set height and width.

```
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", "", "width=200,height=100");
```

To set position center.

```
var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;

var width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;

window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", "", "width=200,height=100, top=' + top + ', left=' + left");
```

Comment: it worked :) and if i want to show up in middle of screen, can we edit the location of popup windows is show up ?

Comment: You can set top and left. window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", "", "width=200,height=100 top=100, left=100");

Comment: it worked (again) sorry for this simple question, i tried to search but the answer i get is too advance for me, still new in javascript.

Comment: Where is ```w``` and ```h``` being declared? And what values are they supposed to hold?

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below:

```
window.open(url, windowTitle, "height=100,width=200");
```

When you specify height and width it will open a new window for you. I checked this with IE and it works fine.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function Warn() {
               alert ("This is a warning message!");
               document.write ("This is a warning message!");
            }

 </script>
```